# Why are urns so common in combinatorics questions?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, terminology, polya-urn-model

My research is in combinatorics and graph theory, and I'm used to phrasing basic combinatorics questions in terms of [balls and bins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins). However, many sources talk about [balls and urns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem). I'd never thought about it until a student brought it up this semester. They asked me why mathematicians are dumping the ashes of their loved ones in order to store coloured balls! I don't have an answer, and I agree that outside of a math class I've only heard urn refer to a vessel for cremated remains.

The linked Wikipedia article mentions Jacob Bernoulli's use of the Latin word *urna*, and its possible roots in old lotteries and elections. Are there are particularly good reasons why the word has persisted in English mathematics? Or is it just another curious survivor like *singular*?

Comment: Most likely due to Benjamin Franklin, who said, "A penny saved is a penny urned"

Comment: They are copying the first person who did it.  After all, one good urn deserves another.

Comment: Not everything revolves around english in the world of mathematics you know. Urne,urna are very common in french, italian and spanish for instance to designate a ballot box, I'm not surprised the word would pass as is from continental european mathematics to british mathematics and then persists being used because of tradition.

Comment: @zwim In fact, I do know that. With words like eigenvalue and étale around, it would be hard to ignore the influence of other languages. If urn's persistence in English mathematics is because of communication with mathematics in another language, that would be an (interesting!) answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

The ancient Greeks used urns instead of ballot boxes. See, for instance, [this](http://blogs.getty.edu/iris/voting-with-the-ancient-greeks/) for a learned discussion and nice picture.

There's also coffee urns, without which we could not prove theorems.

Added 15 Dec:
Humor aside, there are 2 or 3 things going on in the original poster's question, none really mathematical.

First,  culture in general, and mathematical terminology in particular, changes in unpredictable ways, exhibiting both surprising conservative features and their opposite.  One conservative mechanism is the role of culture heros and hero literature: if Bernoulli or William Feller used "urn" in the sense in question, so will we, to some extent.

Second, to be a math student is like visiting  foreign country, where many  things seem different.  Many math words are wierd: why "field" in algebra, or "Gaussian kernel" in probability (what is nut-like about the latter?); to ask why we use these words is like asking why they drive on the wrong side of the road in some countries, or why parking spots are paid for in a different way, or why food names don't match up to one's expectations. The answer: just like foreigners, mathematicians are different, and only sometimes can one figure out how or why, so don't sweat it.

Another thing going on is ignorance of their own language: if your students read the dictionary more, they would realize that "urn" is not exclusively a funerary urn.   Vanity insists, look at [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimchi#/media/File:Kimchi_jar.JPG). The big cylinders with coffee in hotels and bad restaurants are usually called coffee urns: try googling the phrase. A pot or carafe is smaller, small enough to put on a diner's table.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\text{Thou still unravish'd bride of quietness,}\cr
\text{Thou foster-child of silence and slow time,}\cr
\text{Sylvan historian, who canst thus express}\cr
\text{A flowery tale more sweetly than our rhyme:}\cr
\text{What leaf-fring'd legend haunts about thy shape}\cr
\text{Of deities or mortals, or of both,}\cr
\text{In Tempe or the dales of Arcady?}\cr
\text{What men or gods are these? What maidens loth?}\cr
\text{What mad pursuit? What struggle to escape?}\cr
\text{What pipes and timbrels? What wild ecstasy?}\end{array}$$

Comment: how can I buy kimtchi in Mexico?

Comment: With pesos, perhaps?

Comment: I forgot about coffee urns. They are much more commonly called pots or carafes where I am.

Comment: @meph The above is the beginning of ***Ode on a Grecian Urn*** by John Keats. The last two lines are known best  $$\begin{array}{l}\text{Beauty is truth, truth beauty - that is all}\cr
\text{Ye know on earth, and all ye need to know.}\end{array}$$

Comment: This isn't really an answer to my question, as it stands. It doesn't give a reason why urn has persisted, rather than be replaced by bin. Most words are replaced as time goes on, and this feels like a strange one to survive.

Comment: @mephistolotl I have tried to address your comment.  I realize on rereading your last sentence above that  you will not be satisfied, but I think you are wrong about the way language changes, and that the strangeness you feel is due to a quirkt of your character and not to an anomaly of mathematical  terminology.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://www.lovethatkimchi.com/Kimchi_Pots/Adam_Field_Pottery/kimchipot7.gif) I have come up with a new kind of urn problem: "A gourmet restaurant has 1024 kimchi urns, arranged in a 32 by 32 grid.  A saboteur, wishing to discredit the restaurant, puts a contaminant in $k$ of the urns in a randomly chosen row of the grid . How many ..."

Comment: As a USA-ian, I can't say that "bin" is any more common than "urn". And isn't "bin" what you throw trash into in the UK?

Comment: @shoover, no, it's what you throw *rubbish* into in the UK. But you had the right concept.